# SQL UPDATE: previous updated columns value in further columns

Tags: sql

Suppose I have this query:

```
UPDATE TEST SET
     a = a + 23,
     b = (b+5)/a,
     c = c + a + b
WHERE
     d = 6
   OR
     d = 10
```

and the original values of the columns is

```
 a = 0
 b = 5
 c = 10
```

Will the query crash because of the `0` value of `a` (so `(b+5)/a` won't calculate) or will a already have `value = 23`.

The general question is: in an `UPDATE statement`, the values used to update the further columns are the original values of the already updated columns or the updated values?

Are there difference between the database used? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, ...?

**EDIT**

What would be the best practise to have the updated values on the "right side"?

Subqueries will work?

How to solve the problem of multiple values updated? Subqueries should return only 1 value

```
UPDATE TEST SET
     a = a + 23,
     b = (b+5)/(SELECT a FROM TEST WHERE d = 6),
     c = c + a + b
WHERE
     d = 6
   OR
     d = 10
```

Comment: The best practice would be to not rely on having updated values (no, a subquery won’t work) and just use the values that you have right there.

Comment: So I have to extract those values previously... this means loger time execution because of more queries...

Comment: No. In this case, just update `b = (b + 5) / (a + 23), c = c + (a + 23) + ((b + 5) / (a + 23))`. If your situation is more complicated than that, please provide an appropriate example, and you can use variables.

Comment: ...I didn't thought what you wrote... it was not such complicated ;-) The query becomes only much longer because I have to redeclare the same variables many times for a PDO prepared statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all SQL databases I know of *except MySQL*, all updates are done exactly simultaneously, which means a will be zero in the update of b.

In MySQL, [the updates are done in order](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html), which means a will be 23.

[A very simple PostgreSQL example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5967d/1) and a [MySQL example with a different result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5967d/1).

Comment: Why MySQL is working on another way? Is there a particular reason? In the future is it possible that also MySQL will work as the other DBs?

Comment: @Perocat It's just [documented to be that way](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html), however I have no info on why that is the case or whether that will change in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I added to my original question another question if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

In all ANSI compliant database systems, transactions are atomic and isolated, which means they happen all at once.  Your query will crash for the given values.